# How to format the json that is send back to the client using SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

When using `Clients.All.someMethod(myData)` in SignalR, how can you intercept the data that is send back to the client? I know MVC is using a default `JavascripDeserializer`. Is this serializer also used when sending data back to the client using SignalR?

What I want in the end, is to convert `DateTime` C# properties to my own custom format in Json.

Can someone help me / explain to me how to do this?

Edit:

myData can be just a plain object with a DateTime property, but it is also possible that it is a list of integers or dates. It actually doesn't matter, I just want to know how I can interrupt the conversion from C# to Json when using SignalR.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589159/signalr-and-serializing-object-array can give you some clue...

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. I assume that "myData" is some kind of list of some objects with dates. You can prepare the correct format before sending it to clients. Or by using javascript you can convert on client side the dates... you don't know how to read data on client side or what?

Comment: @YoupTube Thanks, I wasn't aware that SignalR uses it's own serialize / deserialize process

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is using JSON.NET for serialization so you can decorate your datetime property with non default datetime formatter or even create your own http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Custom serializer is not possible: [registering JavaScriptSerializer with signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763686/registering-javascriptserializer-with-signalr)